# Installation and Partitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to get up and running with Ubuntu. While installing I selected to do a 20GB allocation (forgetting 25 minimum was recommended and honestly I should have just did 100 at the beginning).

[image]

The 1TB HDD on the bottom is the one we're talking about. The 2 partitions on the right I believe are the Ubuntu partitions.

So what I did was I did Ubuntu install alongside Windows and it threw some type of an error at the end of installation (I can't remember what it was). Ubuntu doesn't show up when I go to the boot menu either unlike when I installed it on my old laptop.

I'm trying to figure out how to combine the Ubuntu partition(s) and the unallocated space and get both Windows and Ubuntu booting, and I don't even know where to begin

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA SanDisk SD8SNAT1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   128GB  127GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      128GB   128GB  523MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  873GB   873GB   ntfs            Basic data partition  msftdata
 2      978GB   979GB   538MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 3      979GB   983GB   4409MB  ext4
 4      983GB   1000GB  17.1GB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: PNY USB 2.0 FD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 8167MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8167MB  8166MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Comment: You have an ESP - efi system partition on sda? Is Windows booting in UEFI mode. Best to see partitioning from Linux. In live installer in live mode, using terminal `sudo parted -l`. Post that above and preserve formatting to make it easy to read.

Comment: @oldfred done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you only gave 4GB to the Ubuntu root partition `/dev/sdb3` and the installation probably failed because the space was not enough.

You should reinstall Ubuntu. In the partitioning step, select *Something else*. I personally would make the root partition in the unallocated space between `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`. I recommend using [LVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html#lvm), so you can resize the partition later. If you really need about 16GB swap, you should consider joining the current `/dev/sdb3` and `/dev/sdb4` into a single swap partition. Otherwise, make a smaller swap partition after `/dev/sdb2`. The remaining space can be added to the root partition if it’s made using LVM (now or later).

### Further reading

- [Ubuntu Swap FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Comment: I'm about to start a coding bootcamp so I want to start developing on Linux, I figure 100GB will allow me to install a few games as well (for instance Rocket League) to play for short breaks during coding binges. When I originally installed it I wasn't paying too close attention (I know I should have but I was excited about my new laptop and my 2 year old was trying to press the pretty new light up keys) but the out of space error sounds correct. I already have 16GB RAM so I think I may (at least according to the FAQ) need that. I'm a very noob novice.I'll give this stuff a try thanks!

Comment: Awesome thanks. I'm in ubuntu now! I marked this as the answer but sorry I can't upvote your answer as I don't have the 15 rep yet :(